# Are (commutative) squares in some sense universal among edge-symmetric double categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, universal-property, functoriality, internal-categories

**Definitions:**
Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, and a [double category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+category) $\mathbb{D}$, i.e. a category [internal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category) to $Cat$ with an “objects category” $\mathcal{D}_0$ and a “morphisms category” $\mathcal{D}_1$, call $\mathbb{D}$ a **“double category over $\mathcal{C}$”** if “$\mathcal{D}_0$ is $\mathcal{C}$”, i.e. if there are functors $\mathbf{F}: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}_0$, $\mathbf{F}^{-1}: \mathcal{D}_0 \to \mathcal{C}$, such that $\mathbf{F}^{-1} \circ \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{Id}_{\mathcal{C}}$ and $\mathbf{F} \circ \mathbf{F}^{-1} = \mathbf{Id}_{\mathcal{D}_0}$ (call this condition “strictly invertible”).

*(The use of equality / "strict" invertibility is deliberate, a natural isomorphism is too weak here and incompatible with the motivation for the question.)*

The morphisms of $\mathcal{D}_0$ are called “vertical morphisms”, the objects of $\mathcal{D}_1$ are called “horizontal morphisms”. We can swap the roles of these two “morphisms” and still get valid categories, $\tilde{\mathcal{D}}_0$ whose objects are the objects of $\mathcal{D}_0$ and whose morphisms are the objects of $\mathcal{D}_1$, and $\tilde{\mathcal{D}}_1$ whose objects are the morphisms of $\mathcal{D}_0$ and whose morphisms are the morphisms of $\mathcal{D}_1$. Moreover, the combination of $\tilde{\mathcal{D}}_0$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{D}}_1$ is again a double category, $\tilde{\mathbb{D}}$, called the “transpose” of $\mathbb{D}$.

A double category $\mathbb{D}$ is called **“edge-symmetric”** if, given its transpose $\tilde{\mathbb{D}}$, one has strictly invertible functors between the objects category $\mathcal{D}_0$ of $\mathbb{D}$ and the objects category $\tilde{\mathcal{D}}_0$ of the transpose $\tilde{\mathbb{D}}$. (Presumably this definition is equivalent to the condition that there are strictly invertible *double* functors between $\mathbb{D}$ and its transpose $\tilde{\mathbb{D}}$, although I haven’t checked.)

Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, and a double category $\mathbb{D}$, unsurprisingly say that $\mathbb{D}$ is **“an edge-symmetric double category over $\mathcal{C}$”** when $\mathbb{D}$ is both “edge-symmetric” and a “double category over $\mathcal{C}$”.

For an arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$, the class $\operatorname{Sq}(\mathcal{C})$ of [squares](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+square) of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ form the 2-cells (morphisms of the morphism category) of an edge-symmetric double category over $\mathcal{C}$. Likewise, the class $\operatorname{ComSq}(\mathcal{C})$ of [*commutative* squares](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+square) of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ also induces an edge-symmetric double category over $\mathcal{C}$.

> **Question:**
> For an arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$, is there any sense in which either $\operatorname{ComSq}(\mathcal{C})$ or $\operatorname{Sq}(\mathcal{C})$ is universal among edge-symmetric double categories over $\mathcal{C}$?
>
> What about among edge-symmetric double categories over $\mathcal{C}$ with additional extra properties, e.g. that are both [left-connected and right-connected](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/right-connected+double+category#examples)?

If I had to guess, it seems like any such universal property would be "right universal", i.e. make $\operatorname{Sq}(\mathcal{C})$ / $\operatorname{CommSq}(\mathcal{C})$ the terminal object in some construction such that given an arbitrary edge-symmetric double category $\mathbb{D}$ over $\mathcal{C}$, there should always be a unique double functor from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\operatorname{Sq}(\mathcal{C})$ / $\operatorname{CommSq}(\mathcal{C})$.

Following the description of "right universal" properties from section 3.8 of [Bergman's *Cook's Tour of Other Universal Constructions*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+category), the “minimal information guaranteed to be associated” to a 2-cell in a general double category is its source horizontal morphism and target horizontal morphism. But in an edge-symmetric double category, the minimal information guaranteed to be associated to a 2-cell is not only the source and target horizontal morphisms, but also the source and target vertical morphisms for the corresponding 2-cell in the transpose double category. This seems very similar to the minimal information guaranteed to be associated to a square of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. to a 2-cell in $\operatorname{Sq}(\mathcal{C})$ considered as a double category. Of course, commutative squares are better behaved than arbitrary squares, so it would be nice to restrict to $\operatorname{ComSq}(\mathcal{C})$, but I don’t see why that should always be possible.

**Note:** I asked [this question previously on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4870033/are-commutative-squares-in-some-sense-universal-among-edge-symmetric-double-ca), but it went unanswered for two weeks. I remain unsure whether this question should be considered "research-level" and appropriate for MathOverflow. This question is essentially a follow-up to / clarification of a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864856/among-morphisms-of-morphisms-what-makes-commutative-squares-special) that is fairly basic. If nothing else, it seems like double categories remain a developing area of research, and that the only major monograph about them was written by a leading active researcher in the field to collect the most important current results.

- Marco Grandis, Higher dimensional categories: from double to multiple categories, World Scientific, 2019, doi:10.1142/11406

**Related question:** [Is it possible to approach higher categories from the point of view of the arrow functor?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114620/is-it-possible-to-approach-higher-categories-from-the-point-of-view-of-the-arrow)